# Почему — половой?

Tags: этимология

Скажите, пожалуйста, почему прислугу в трактирах раньше называли "половыми"?

Comment: половой т е исполнитель заказа

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я думала, что в обязанности "половых" входила изначально и уборка полов. Но маловероятно, чтобы это могло отразиться на их названии, поскольку это совсем не основное занятие и даже не второстепенное.

У Гиляровского подробностей о самом слове "половой" немного. Половой еще назывался "белорубашечником" или "шестеркой". "Белорубашечники" от того, что носили обязательно белые мадаполамовые (данное "иноземное" *:)* слово вряд ли могло повлиять, но пусть будет) рубашки или реже голландского полотна.

А вот "полова" - это интереснее! По Далю одно из значений этого слова (помимо хлебной мякины и пр.) - "Вянуть, блекнуть, чавреть; линять, терять цвет, краску, желтеть". За уши можно притянуть к производству или же износу рубашек (хотя у Гиляровского именно речь о белых!) И у того же Даля есть еще один нюанс.  Полова - "...Арх. выдыхаться, терять от лежки вкус, запах, крепость. Чай половеет у вас, видно плохо держите его." Тоже можно каким-то боком притянуть к половым.

Вот такие варианты. Жду помидоров в свой адрес :) (можно конфетами).

Comment: У меня помидор - только один. От половы - было бы скорее пол**о**вый.
Все остальное - вполне соответствует тому уровню, что все остальные версии. Я только не понял, Вы полову связываете с рубашками? Или независимо?

Comment: Первое значение "половы" к рубашке, а второе , наверно, к невкусному чаю...

Answer (score 2):

Половой прислуживал посетителям трактира, может, и супчик им разливал в тарелки **половником**?! Версия.

Comment: А ещё у них были **поло**тенца.

Answer (score 2):

Да и у Фасмера "половой" от "пол" в первом значении, где этот самый "пол" еще и *спальная лавка*.

Comment: Выкрики с места — не ответ.

Comment: Я хотела добавить комментарий к ответу со сканом из Преображенского, но вчера еще не могла такой опцией воспользоваться.

Comment: Так ведь Shry Philip дал, похоже, этот скан ещё весной, но только ответ из словарной статьи автоматом не получается. Ну, версией назвал, и что? Разве в этой статье есть ответ на ясный вопрос: почему?

Comment: Мы с вами можем только предполагать. Не думаю, что еще есть возможность точно ответить. А версии, собственно, для того, чтобы думать.

Answer (score 1):

Навскидку - потому, что он **по полу** бегал. 
На самом деле - далеко не всякую прислугу. И не только в трактирах. 
Обычно так называли официантов и вообще тех, кто непосредственно общался с клиентами.
Это накладывало на половых определенные требования - но и ставило их в относительно привилегированное положение по сравнению, например, с посудомойками.

Comment: А "пол**о**ва" тогда откуда? 
Мне кажется, тут должно быть глубже.

Comment: Нашла в Инете версию, подобную вашей с уточнением, что по полу они (половые) не только ходили, но и спали на нем.

Answer (score 1):

Есть еще такой вариант

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ЭТИМОЛОГИЧЕСКИЙ СЛОВАРЬ РУССКОГО ЯЗЫКА. СОСТАВИЛ А. Преображенский, Заслуж преподаватель Московской 4-й гимназии. ТОМ ВТОРОЙ 1910-1914

Answer (score 1):

Слышал я такую версию... в большинстве трактиров основной пол был земляной или в лучшем случае из черновой доски, а столики для господ размещались на своего рода кафедрах или возвышениях из досок(чтобы сидеть было теплее, не на земле) - иначе говоря половой это тот кто ходит по полу... лично мне кажется правдоподобным

Comment: Иначе говоря - они весь вечер были на арене.